# Android: Find the string resource key by the string value

Tags: android, android-resources

There are a lot of explanations out there in how to retrieve a string resource value by its key. But I actually need the solution for the reverse case - retrieving the key by the value instead.

You may wonder why would I ever need something like that. Well, I got speech recognition in my app and in case there's a non-english speaker input, I need to recover the localized string key from the raw voice-to-text input so I can have multilanguage speech recognition support in my app.

So imagine I had a string resource:

```html
// EN
<string name="not_a_dog">Cat</string>
// DE
<string name="not_a_dog">Katze</string>
```

So in case user says "Cat" (or "Katze" for German locale), I would get "not_a_dog".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to declare mutiple strings for different languages

Just create `string.xml` for each languages like described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages); then you can do : `if(yourText.equals(getString(R.string.not_a_dog)){
       //do what you want
      }`